# What is the song name played after Kaneki kills dragon (19:30 - 23:42) in 12th episode of Tokyo Ghoul :Re 2?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

There is a song played just after Kaneki destroys dragon and it continues till the end. It starts from 19:30 and ends at 23:42. Can you please tell me its name?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, earlier I thought if I asked questions related to soundtracks on this site, I'd get answers. After watching Tokyo Ghoul re episode 23, I posted 2 questions, and after watching episode 24 I posted one being this question only. Till now, I've found 2 out of the 3.

Now, answer to this question:

That song is Won't Forget You by Yutaka Yamada.
https://youtu.be/Iie-omxoyt0